# UITap Gesture Not being recognized

Tags: swift, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a view controller with a button that has the following action.

```
@IBAction func sourceButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let menu = sourceMenu()
    menu.openMenu()
}
```

The source menus class is an NSObject class with the following code.

```
class sourceMenu: NSObject {
    let blackView = UIView()

    public func openMenu(){

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({ $0.isKeyWindow }).first {
            blackView.frame = window.frame
            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
            blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissMenu)))
            window.addSubview(blackView)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.blackView.alpha = 1
            }
        }


    }

    @objc public func dismissMenu(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.blackView.alpha = 0

        }
    }

}
```

the function dismissMenu is not being called when I tap on the view controller. any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to enable the user interaction? `blackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: yes i tried it. didn't work.

Comment: window.bringSubviewToFront(blackView)

Comment: window.isUserINteractionEnabled = false

Comment: still doesn't work :(

Comment: blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1). The alpha should be 1 for user interaction to work

Comment: I saw a post about this. I tried it and nothing worked. I am convinced that my selector or my method is not being called. I don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is really that your object is being released from memory since it only lives within your function block. Once the function finishes its execution your memory gets cleared. You need to create an instance in your presenting `UIViewController` so the `arc` keeps it alive since the view controller will have a reference to it. You should declare a property like so.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let menu = sourceMenu()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }

  @IBAction func tapAction(_ sender: Any) {
    menu.openMenu()
  }

}
```

Also you could just grab a reference to the **keyWindow** by simply doing `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow`

Also what's your reason for presenting this on the window instead of using your view controller? If this is something that every controller should be able to present why not making an extension instead? I would avoid presenting views from the window as it could lead to hidden issues.

Comment: Well spotted! Didn't even notice that the menu would be dereferenced.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue once. The solution I found for myself was having a strong reference to the `UITapGestureRecognizer`. So what you should do is:

```
// Define a gesture variable in class
class sourceMenu: NSObject {
    var gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer
}

// Use the variable in `openMenu` function
gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissMenu)) 
blackView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it didn't work as well. I think the function isn't being called at this point not that the gesture is not recognized. do you have any other ideas? I tried almost everything there is...

Comment: The reason given in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59104671/3050006) might be the issue as well.